# Words and Words with "ver-" Prefix

Tags: standard-german

If a word and the same word with a "ver-" prefix mean "essentially" the same thing, are there any general differences between them? If so, what are they?

Examples:

Folgen / Verfolgen

Prügeln / Verprügeln

(Others that I can't remember... haha)

Comment: dingen - verdingen (*jemanden dingen* is a bit old-fashioned, though)

Comment: I do actually think there are differences in meaning between "folgen" and "verfolgen", or "prügeln" and "verprügeln", i.e. they don't essentially mean the same thing. E.g. "Folgen" = "follow", while "verfolgen" = "prosecute, trail, chase, pursue".

Comment: "Kaufen" and "Verkaufen" are certainly not essentially the same thing...

Answer (score 6):

The function of the affix *ver-* are manifold in German. This is summarized in a rather concise list in the [DWDS entry on its etymology (Pfeifer)](https://dwds.de/wb/ver-) (*translation by me, examples from Pfeifer)*:

> The prefix *ver-* is used to express that something/somebody is
>
> - being removed, carried away: *verrücken, vertreiben, verzerren*
> - vanishing, decays: *verdunsten, verklingen, verschwinden*
> - misleading, going wrong: *verführen, verwechseln, sich verzählen*
> - being negated: *verbieten, versagen*
> - resulting in something: *verbluten, verpacken, vertilgen*
> - is being intensified: *verschließen, versperren*
> - made transitive from intransitive: *verfolgen, verheiraten, verspotten*
> - a verbal derivation from an adjective: *verdeutlichen, vergöttern, verarmen, verholzen*

I believe the list may be incomplete but it should give you an idea. From your two examples *verfolgen* is resulting from *folgen*, *verprügeln* is an intensification from *prügeln*.

Over the time the original meaning of one or the other verb affixed with *ver-* may also get lost or changes, so it is always a good idea to look up a given verb in a dictionary.

Another recommended resource where you can look up if the prefix *ver-* exists for a given verb or noun is the "Wordformation" browser from [canoo.net](http://www.canoonet.eu/services/Controller?input=pr%C3%BCgel&features=(Cat+N)(Gender+M)&dispatch=wordformation&lang=en), in the link here shown for *prügeln*. You can not only see what prefixes or compounds exist but you can also click on any entry for more information including links to dictionaries.

Comment: "verheiraten" is an odd example. Isn’t "heiraten" already transitive?

Comment: @idmean You can say "Wir heiraten" or "ich heirate dich", but the subject of "verheiraten" would be neither bride nor broom (perhaps a parent or a priest)

Comment: @HagenVonEitzen the parent (?) or priest who does *verheiraten* is the agent (and other terminology might exist). The bride and groom are still the grammatical subject in passive constructions. They are the subjects anyway, colloquially speaking.

Answer (score 5):

[Online-Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/ver_) gives the following list

1. Expresses in conjuction with verbs that something is depleted, eliminated or no longer exists as a result of the action.

   Examples: verforschen, verfrühstücken, verwarten
2. Expresses in conjuction with verbs that someone spends time on doing something.

   Examples: verschlafen, verschnarchen, verspielen
3. Expresses in conjuction with verbs that someone is doing something wrongly  or incorrectly

   Examples: verbremsen, verinszenieren
4. Expresses in conjuction with verbs that something is being impaired by an action

   Examples: verwaschen, verwohnen
5. Has no impact at all on the meaning in conjuction with verbs

   Examples: verbleiben, verbringen, vermelden

Thus, in many cases it is (5), but there are  cases where the prefix actually changes the meaning of the base verb.

Fun fact: "ver-" is the most common prefix for German verbs - nearly 50% of the non-separable prefixed verbs start with it.

Comment: Errrm - the first 3 entries appear to be missing. Apart from that, and to be honest, I do not believe in this Duden list. I mean, why do they come up with *verforschen, verinszenieren, verfeaturen*? These are not really common verbs, at least not in my microenvironment. Also, I must disagree that *verbleiben, verbringen, vermelden* are identical to *bleiben, bringen, melden*. A word of critisism may be worth to be included in your answer (still +1 from me because this list is way out of your responsibility).

Comment: @Takkat The first 3 entries in the Duden do not refer to verbs, so do not apply to this question. With regards to the selected examples - maybe not the most common examples, but work for me.

Comment: 4. *vergolden* e.g is not negative, just changing state. 5. *verbringen should be 1. and 2., which are nearly equal anyway. *was zu vermelden haben* is rather negative, but could it be akin to *vor-*?